# Is it weird that I like my red wines slightly chilled?

Tags: drinking, red-wine, preparation-for-drinking

Is it weird that I like my red wines Slightly chilled? Or is this normal? I constantly hear that we should be drinking reds at “room temperature."

Comment: No weird, as red wine should be served at "cellar temperature" which is cooler than you think.

Comment: I don't feel this is a duplicate. The question isn't asking what the recommended serving temperatures are, but whether it is odd that they might prefer them served at a different temperature.

Comment: @Dave The linked accepted answer clearly states that the recommended serving temperature is cooler than room temperature which answers this question.

Answer (score 2):

No, it is not weird.  In social situations, such as hosting an event, you should serve the wine at the recommended temperatures only to meet the expectations of your guests.  If you are just talking about yourself, you should drink it at whatever you find the most pleasurable.

There is much too much nonsense surrounding wine where perceived quality depends too much on the [design of the label](https://ellenwine.com/study-wine-labels-influence-judgement/), [the price](http://www.caltech.edu/news/wine-study-shows-price-influences-perception-1374), and [the reputation](http://oega.boku.ac.at/fileadmin/user_upload/Tagung/2010/Short_paper_2010/59_HuberWeiss-OEGA_TB_2010.pdf), and very little depends upon the actual liquid itself.  There is a reason that wine competitions are not blind tastings because the few times they have done them that way, the recognized "best" have not done so well.  The California wine industry burst on the international scene because of the infamous [Judgement of Paris](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Judgment_of_Paris_(wine)), which was done blind (at least one of the French judges was so outraged that California wines won, that she [demanded her ballot back](https://www.npr.org/sections/thesalt/2016/05/24/479163882/the-judgment-of-paris-the-blind-taste-test-that-decanted-the-wine-world) for the wines they themselves heaped much praise upon).  In a delicious bit of irony, in blind tastings "[Two Buck Chuck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charles_Shaw_wine)" has [taken double gold medals](https://www.npr.org/templates/story/story.php?storyId=1963794) in blind tastings over the "best" California wines, leading to some California wine industry people to cry foul over the results just as the French did 25 years earlier.

Drink what you enjoy served however you enjoy it best, because isn't that the whole point in the first place?

Comment: Truthfully this is a bit of a rant. The entire second paragraph is unrelated to the question (in my humble opinion). Please note I'm not disagreeing with your comments.

Comment: I don't disagree that the second paragraph is a little bit of a rant, but in my opinion it is a rant that goes to the question asked; it addresses the feeling that one is doing wine the "wrong way", whereas I point out that a good deal of the norms and, yes, I'll say "snobbery", is [built on a house of cards](https://www.thebillfold.com/2016/09/confessions-of-a-former-wine-snob/) to begin with.  If I wanted to make it a full-blown rant, I would have mentioned the whole [cork vs. screw cap](https://winefolly.com/tutorial/corks-vs-screw-caps/) issue.  :)

Comment: The question was closed since it is a duplicate anyway. However, the simple answer to whether his preferring his red wine slightly chilled is that is normal normal because the recommended temperature of "cellar temperature" is somewhat cooler than typical room temperatures. It is okay to add the comment that it is perfectly fine to drink your wine at any temperature you like it. I think a lot of people drink white wine too cold, but I don't argue about it.